# Is "fireplace" more normal than "hearth" when describing what's in a house?

Tags: synonyms, british-english

I came across someone saying that their house (located in the UK) has a hearth. I would have used *fireplace*. Is *hearth* used that commonly nowadays, or is it a bit archaic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words are related, but not identical.

In common usage, a [*fireplace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireplace) is a semi-open box made of brick or other heat-radiating and non-flammable material. It is built into the structure of the building and contains burning wood to generate heat.

A [*hearth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearth) is an open fireplace without an oven. Think of a central firepit in a medieval hall. It captures the idea of gathering around a fire on multiple sides.

Of course, English being what it is, the meaning of *hearth* has shifted over the years. It is now usually used to refer to a non-flammable portion of the floor in front of a fireplace, or a raised platform on which the fireplace rests.

In the case of your friend, I think it likely that the intended meaning was "an open burning location" rather than "a spot in front of the fire".

Answer (score 0):

Since [*hearth*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hearth?q=hearth) means the floor or the area in front of the fireplace, I think it's used [synecdochically](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synecdoche?q=synecdoche) and it actually stands for *fireplace*.